# GWT DND changing DataTransfer image or cursor

Tags: javascript, gwt, drag-and-drop

When you go to this page for example : http://grooveshark.com/#!/search?q=stackoverflow and then start dragging any song you get this nice Drag and Drop behavior :

[image: Drag started]

Then, during the Drag and Drop, when you are hovering a zone that accepts the drop, the image under the cursor changes to display that a drop is possible :

[image: Drag Over]

Is there any chance to get this kind of thing working with `GWT` ?

I've made a dummy widget for some text, and changing the DragImage after the drag have started, do not seems to work. I've also tried changing the cursor, but without success

```java
@Override
        public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
            dragIndicator.setInnerText("CAN DROP !");
            event.getDataTransfer().setDragImage(dragIndicator,
                    10, 10);
        }
```

It's nice to have the Drag and Drop capabilities, but as I've seen here http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#BinExample we can only modify the hovered element. **Am I wrong ?**

**EDIT**

Upon reading the W3C (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dnd.html#the-drag-data-store) I've encountered this :

> The dropEffect attribute controls the drag-and-drop feedback that the
>   user is given during a drag-and-drop operation. When the DataTransfer
>   object is created, the dropEffect attribute is set to a string value.
>   On getting, it must return its current value. On setting, if the new
>   value is one of "none", "copy", "link", or "move", then the
>   attribute's current value must be set to the new value. Other values
>   must be ignored.

However, I didn't find anything like that in the GWT code, maybe I will try it using JSNI (have to check if it's a standard or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to change the cursor during the hovering (tested only in FF 15) using JSNI. **This is far from being complete and correct.**

```java
public class MonWidget extends Widget implements HasAllDragAndDropHandlers {

private DivElement mainDiv;

public MonWidget()
{
    mainDiv = Document.get().createDivElement();

    SpanElement span1 = Document.get().createSpanElement();
    span1.setInnerText("span1");
    span1.setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);
    span1.getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");

    SpanElement span2 = Document.get().createSpanElement();
    span2.setInnerText("span2");
    span2.setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);
    span2.getStyle().setBackgroundColor("blue");    

    mainDiv.appendChild(span1);
    mainDiv.appendChild(span2);

    setElement(mainDiv);

    this.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
        public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {

            Element element = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
            event.setData("text", "some data");
            event.getDataTransfer().setDragImage(element,
                    10, 10);        
        }
    });

    this.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
            setEffet(event.getNativeEvent(),"copy");
            //setEffet(event.getNativeEvent(),"link");
            // THIS do not seems to work - setEffet(event.getNativeEvent(),"move");
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
}
....
```

And the JSNI method :

```java
public final native void setEffet(NativeEvent e, String effect) /*-{
     var dt = e.dataTransfer;
     dt.dropEffect = effect;
  }-*/;
```